# Im trying to add increase a level when you reach a certain amount of clicks tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a simple clicking game and the I can't seem to figure out how to increase the level when I reach a certain amount of clicks. For example, every time a user clicks a button they gain clicks, and when they reach a certain amount of clicks they level up

If anyone knows how to fix this problem it would be wonderful if you share!

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import time
from PIL import ImageTk, Image



root = Tk()



root.geometry('450x350')
root.title('Clicking Game')


root.configure(bg='blue')
level = 1
clicks = 0
label = tk.Label(root, text='Experiance: '+str(clicks), background='blue', foreground='white')
level_label = tk.Label(root,background='blue',foreground='white' ,text='Level: '+str(level))
photo = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\mosta\Downloads\python-transparent-background.png")


def on_click():
    global clicks, levels
    clicks += 1
    label.config(text='Experiance: '+str(clicks))

    level_label.config(text='Level: '+str(level))



    if clicks >= 100:
        clicks += 10

    if clicks >= 50:
        clicks += 5

    if clicks >= 10:
        clicks += 2

    if clicks >= 200:
        clicks += 20

    if clicks >= 300:
        clicks += 30

    if clicks >= 400:
        clicks += 40

    if clicks >= 500:
        clicks += 50

    if clicks >= 600:
        clicks += 60

    if clicks >= 10000:
        clicks += 1





label.pack(side=TOP)
label.config(font=('Arial', 30, 'bold', 'italic'))
level_label.pack(side=BOTTOM)
level_label.config(font=('Arial', 30, 'bold', 'italic'))
button = tk.Button(root,borderwidth=10,width=60,height=60, text = 'Click Me !', image = photo, command=on_click)
button.place(x=625, y=300)



#leveling system

def level_claim():
    global level, clicks
    if clicks >= 10000:
        claim_level.pack(side=RIGHT)
        level += 1


claim_level = tk.Button(text='Claim Level', bg='pink', foreground='red', command=level_claim)
level_congrats = tk.Label(root, text='Congratulations You have reached level 2!\n'
                                             'Keeping leveling up to unlock more features')




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the program doing that's different from what you expect? What have you done to debug this?

Comment: I tried making a different button that when it reaches a certain amount of clicks a new button appears and when you click it you gain a level but It still didn't work

Comment: I don't understand what the purpose of those `if` inside `on_click()`.

Comment: Its to execute a command when it reaches a certain amount of clicks

Comment: If you are at 500 clicks, for each click you are adding (1+10+5+2+20+30+40+50) to the clicks value. Is that what you intended to do?